# How to succesfully make a POST request with JS fetch to a Django REST API

Tags: javascript, django, post, fetch-api

I've been trying unsuccesfully to make a POST request to my API end point, and I always get an error. My setup is a django server with a rest API, and I'm trying to add a reservation to the Booking Model, using fetch.

This is the code inside my "onSubmit" js function (when the submit button is clicked):

```
                csrf = document.getElementsByName("csrfmiddlewaretoken")[0].value;
                const formdata = new FormData(form);
                fetch('/api/booking/', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        "X-CSRF-Token":csrf,
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    },
                    credentials: "same-origin",
                    body: formdata
                })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => console.log(data));
```

models.py

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(User,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
    hour = models.SmallIntegerField(
        null=False,
        default=12,
        validators=[ #from 8am to 10pm
            MaxValueValidator(22),
            MinValueValidator(8)
        ],
    )
    
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('date', 'hour')
```

forms.py

```
class BookingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ['date', 'hour', 'client']
```

views.py (of the api endpoint /api/booking/

```
class BookingView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Booking.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookingSerializer
```

So this is the error I get in the Chrome JS console:

```
book:159     POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/booking/ 400 (Bad Request)
onSubmit @ book:159
book:169 {detail: 'JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'}detail: "JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: use the async and await method to fetch API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`csrf` is not required in REST APIs services. Thus, you do not need to set any headers in your request. Although, you have an [authentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#authentication) system in place and your view just does not know how to handle it:

```py
class BookingListCreateAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Booking.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookingSerializer
    authentication_classes = [BasicAuthentication]
```

Aside from that it is always good practice to use the latest features such as [`arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#syntax) and `async/await`, introduced with ES6. That being said, your template should be similar to this:

```
<body>
    <form>
        {{form}}
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="sendForm()">
    </form>

    <script>
        const sendForm = async (event) => {
            const url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/bookings/';

            const formElement = document.querySelector("form");
            const formData = new FormData(formElement);
            
            const res = await fetch(url, { 
                method: "POST", 
                body: formData 
            });

            if (res.status === 201) {
                console.log('Booking successfully created!');
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your content type for the body is JSON but you are trying to send FormData. Convert the FormData to JSON first before putting it in the request body.

```
var object = {};
formdata.forEach(function(value,key){
object[key] = value});

fetch('/api/booking/', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
      "X-CSRF-Token":csrf,
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
       },
   credentials: "same-origin",
   body: JSON.stringify(object)
   })
```

Comment: Thanks but I now get this error, and I really don't understand since the csrf token is actually passed in the headers and in the form in objects['csrfmiddlewaretoken']. this is the error : POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/booking/ 403 (Forbidden)
onSubmit @ book:173
book:183 {detail: 'CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing.'}

Comment: When I logout from the site, I can actually perform the fetch without any problem but when I'm logged in is when I get this error. Weird